# How do I find & replace a url using Notepad++ and regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, url, replace, notepad++

I've been searching on this for a while now and am yet to find out how to do what exactly I'm trying to do.

I need to search a folder and locate files that contain an href tag with a specific base url. I have accomplished this with the following regular expression:

```
(href="(https:\/\/www\.mytesturl\.com))
```

After locating the files and locations where this URL is used, I need to do a replace on the located text. This is where my issue is. The href attribute will definitely contain the text:

https://www.mytesturl.com

Additionally, it may contain any manner of query string values or "/" paths after this.

Ultimately, my find/replace operation needs to yield the result:

```
href='<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + "<extra>" %>'
```

Where `<extra>` is everything from the end of ".com" to the end of the initial href value in quotes.

So

> https://www.mytesturl.com?somevar=somevalue&secondvar=secondvalue

Would be:

> href='<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host +
>   "?somevar=somevalue&secondvar=secondvalue" %>'

and

https://www.mytesturl.com/otherpath?somevar=somevalue&secondvar=secondvalue

Would be:

> href='<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host +
>   "/otherpath?somevar=somevalue&secondvar=secondvalue" %>'

Can Notepad++ do a regex find/replace such as this?

Answer (score 1):

You already have several problems, and they all stem from using Regexes when you shouldn't use Regexes. Write yourself a little PHP script to iterate through the directory, parse each HTML file, navigate the DOMs to find `a` tags and inspect their `href` properties... then rewrite them (for *that* you can use a regex!).

If you're okay with having false negatives, though (i.e. some occurrences not found), then yes you can do this … using captures and backreferences.

So, you could search for:

```
href="https:\/\/www\.mytesturl\.com([^"]*)"
//                                 ^^^^^^^
//                             optional capture
//                         any characters until '"'
```

and replace it with:

```
href='<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + "\1" %>'
//                                                         ^^
//                                                 contents of capture
//                                               (which may be nothing!)
```

As an aside, you really should be using `&`, not `+`, for string concatenation in ASP.

Furthermore, the Notepad++ manual (press F1) on the "Find" topic explains that the application uses the Scintilla regular expression engine, and links to [the Scintilla documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html), which is a pretty handy reference for this kind of work. *Always read the documentation.*